# Validation: how to check for specific error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know how to check an attribute for errors:

```
@post.errors[:title].any?
```

Is it possible to check which validation failed (for example "uniqueness")?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By "taken", I assume you mean that the title already exists in the database. I further assume that you have the following line in your `Post` model:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :title
```

Personally, I think that checking to see if the title is already taken by checking the validation errors is going to be fragile.  `@post.errors[:title]` will return something like `["has already been taken"]`.  But what if you decide to change the error message or if you internationalize your application?  I think you'd be better off writing a method to do the test:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  def title_unique?
    Post.where(:title => self.title).count == 0
  end
end
```

Then you can test if the title is unique with `@post.title_unique?`.  I wouldn't be surprised if there's already a Rubygem that dynamically adds a method like this to ActiveRecord models.

Comment: Well, I could also use "Post.exists?(:title => @post.title)" but I was wondering if there is a easy way to detect which validation failed. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 7):

Recently I came across a situation where I need the same thing: The user can add/edit multiple records at once from a single form.

Since at validation time not all records have been written to the database I cannot use @David's solution. To make things even more complicated it is possible that the records already existing in the database can become duplicates, which are detected by the uniqueness validator.

**TL;DR:** You can't check **for a specific *validator***, but you can **check for a specific *error*.**

I'm using this:

```rb
# The record has a duplicate value in `my_attribute`, detected by custom code.
if my_attribute_is_not_unique?
  # Check if a previous uniqueness validator has already detected this:
  unless @record.errors.added?(:my_attribute, :taken)
    # No previous `:taken` error or at least a different text.
    @record.errors.add(:my_attribute, :taken) 
  end
end
```

Some remarks:

- It does work with I18n, but you have to provide the same interpolation parameters to `added?` as the previous validator did.
- This doesn't work if the previous validator has written a custom message instead of the default one (`:taken`)

Comment: This questions TLDR could be updated to include `errors.details` which makes this possible. More at http://stackoverflow.com/a/41675301/67834

Answer (score 5):

Regarding checking for uniqueness validation specifically, this didn't work for me:

```rb
@post.errors.added?(:title, :taken)
```

It seems the behaviour has changed so the value must also be passed. This works:

```rb
@post.errors.added?(:title, :taken, value: @post.title)
```

That's the one to use ^ but these also work:

```rb
@post.errors.details[:title].map { |e| e[:error] }.include? :taken
```

```rb
@post.errors.added?(:title, 'has already been taken')
```

Ref [#34629](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/34629), [#34652](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/34652)

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Rails 5+ you can use `errors.details`. For earlier Rails versions, use the backport gem: https://github.com/cowbell/active_model-errors_details

```
is_duplicate_title = @post.errors.details[:title].any? do |detail|
  detail[:error] == :uniqueness
end
```

Rails Guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#working-with-validation-errors-errors-details