# Pass validation to the controller rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I check if the validation is true and use it in a condition in the controller?

Model

```
validate :no_reservation_overlap

scope :overlapping, ->(period_start, period_end) do
  where "((date_start <= ?) and (date_end >= ?))", period_end, period_start
end

private

def no_reservation_overlap
  if (Reservation.overlapping(date_start, date_end).any?)
     errors.add(:date_end, 'it overlaps another reservation')
  end
end
```

Link for more information: [Date range overlap per user rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47285635/date-range-overlap-per-user-rails)

I want to be able to check if validation is true and pass it to the controller

Controller

```
   if validation == true 
      #do something
   end
```

I tried using `on: create` to prevent it from executing a `create` action.

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-validators

Comment: I answered this but I think you actually want to check just this validation, not all validations?

Comment: BTW, the `create` method will not save a record to the database if the record is not valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just call `valid?` on an [ActiveRecord](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html) object.  For example:

```
@reservation = Reservation.new(reservation_params)

if @reservation.valid?
  # Do something if any validation fails
  if @reservation.errors[:date_end].include? 'it overlaps another reservation' 
    # Do something if the overlapping validation fails
  end
end
```

You can read more about validations in the [Ruby on Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html)

If you want to check for a specific validation error, you can look at [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7311198/validation-how-to-check-for-specific-error).

Comment: Last question how about for the no_reservation_overlap, how can I check if it returns true and use it in the controller. The same as no_reservation_overlap.valid?

Comment: To do that, you would have to modify the `no_reservation_overlap` method to return `true` or `false` based on the result of the validation.  Right now, all it does is add an error to the `errors` object.   An alternative approach is to query the `errors` object to see if the `no_reservation_overlap` validation failed.  You would have to call `valid?` or `save` or another method that triggers validation, and then you can simply search the `errors` object for a particular error,  I modified my answer to demonstrate this approach.

Answer (score 1):

`if @user.valid?
  do something
end`